# sendmsg got Bad address

Tags: c, network-programming

When learning about network programming(TCP) I came across this problem:
I tried to use sendmsg() and recvmsg() to exchange info between client and server, but "sendmsg()" got error "BAD ADDRESS".
Some answers on stackoverflow mentioned memory problem, but I am still confused and didn't know what to do.
Here's the code(relative parts) and the result.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with the problem.

```
void process_conn_server(int s) //s is the socketfd
{
    char buffer[30];
    ssize_t size = 0;
    struct msghdr msg;

    struct iovec *v = (struct iovec *)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct iovec));
    if (!v)
    {
        perror("wrong: allocate memory\n");
        return;
    }

    msg.msg_name = NULL;
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;
    msg.msg_iov = v;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 30;
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    // vs = v;
    v[0].iov_base = buffer;
    v[1].iov_base = buffer + 10;
    v[2].iov_base = buffer + 20;
    v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;

    for (;;)
    {
        size = recvmsg(s, &msg, 0);
        if (size == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        sprintf(v[0].iov_base, "%d ", size);
        sprintf(v[1].iov_base, "bytes alt");
        sprintf(v[2].iov_base, "ogether\n");

        v[0].iov_len = strlen(v[0].iov_base);
        v[1].iov_len = strlen(v[1].iov_base);
        v[2].iov_len = strlen(v[2].iov_base);

        sendmsg(s, &msg, 0);
    }
}
```

```
void process_conn_client(int s)
{
    char buffer[30];
    ssize_t size = 0;
    struct msghdr msg;

    struct iovec *v = (struct iovec *)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct iovec));
    if (!v)
    {
        perror("wrong: allocate memory\n");
        return;
    }

    msg.msg_name = NULL;
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;
    msg.msg_iov = v;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 30;
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    // vc = v;
    v[0].iov_base = buffer;
    v[1].iov_base = buffer + 10;
    v[2].iov_base = buffer + 20;
    v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;

    // int fd;
    for (;;)
    {
        // fd = open("firstfile.txt", O_RDONLY, 0666);
        size = read(0, v[0].iov_base, 10);
        printf("%d size\n", size);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            //读到数据，发送给服务器
            v[0].iov_len = size;

            if (sendmsg(s, &msg, 0) < 0)
            {
                perror("");
                return;
            }

            v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;
            size = recvmsg(s, &msg, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (v[i].iov_len > 0)
                {
                    write(1, v[i].iov_base, v[i].iov_len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result:
(base)  qin@qin-D  ~/JuniorB/NetworkProgramming/7   master ●  ./client 127.0.0.1
hello
6 size
Bad address

Other parts should have been right.(I didn't upload it here for they are a little long) . When I use the 2 functions below, this is what i got(and also what i want):

```
void process_conn_client1(int s)
{
    char buffer[30];
    ssize_t size = 0;
    //申请三块结构类型
    struct iovec *v = (struct iovec *)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct iovec));
    if (!v)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return;
    }

    vc = v;
    //挂接全局变量，便于释放管理

    v[0].iov_base = buffer;
    v[1].iov_base = buffer + 10;
    v[2].iov_base = buffer + 20;
    v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;

    int i = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        size = read(0, v[0].iov_base, 10);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            //读到数据，发送给服务器
            v[0].iov_len = size;
            writev(s, v, 1);

            v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;
            size = readv(s, v, 3);

            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (v[i].iov_len > 0)
                {
                    write(1, v[i].iov_base, v[i].iov_len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    void process_conn_server1(int s)
{
    char buffer[30];
    ssize_t size = 0;
    //申请三块结构类型
    struct iovec *v = (struct iovec *)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct iovec));
    if (!v)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return;
    }

    vs = v;
    v[0].iov_base = buffer;
    v[1].iov_base = buffer + 10;
    v[2].iov_base = buffer + 20;
    v[0].iov_len = v[1].iov_len = v[2].iov_len = 10;

    for (;;)
    {
        size = readv(s, v, 3);
        if (size == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        sprintf(v[0].iov_base, "%d ", size);
        sprintf(v[1].iov_base, "bytes alt");
        sprintf(v[2].iov_base, "ogether\n");

        v[0].iov_len = strlen(v[0].iov_base);
        v[1].iov_len = strlen(v[1].iov_base);
        v[2].iov_len = strlen(v[2].iov_base);

        writev(s, v, 3);
    }
}
```

the result:
(base)  qin@qin-D  ~/JuniorB/NetworkProgramming/7   master ●  ./client 127.0.0.1
hello
6 bytes altogether
input this line and server returns the length
10 bytes altogether
10 bytes altogether
10 bytes altogether
10 bytes altogether
6 bytes altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "sendmsg()" got error "BAD ADDRESS".

for the first case in *process_conn_client* just replace

> ```
> msg.msg_iovlen = 30;
> ```

by

```
 msg.msg_iovlen = 3;
```

because *v* contains 3 entries rather than 30 (probably you put 30 because of the 3 buffers of 10)

---

Out of that still in *process_conn_client* because you read only up to 10 characters from *stdin* doing

> ```
> size = read(0, v[0].iov_base, 10);
> ```

only the first part of the sent buffer can be initialized and the next two are not initialized when you send them